# Check value for cell in Excel by VB

Tags: excel, vba

i want to check about selected cells in excel and hide row if value in this cell equal to zero.
Ex..
Cell from E4 to E10, i want to make loop for value in this cells and hide row if value of cell equals to zero

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What is the problem you are seeing?

Comment: I make it for one cell but i tried to make a loop for selected cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below sample code for your solution.

```
Sub Hide()
    Dim i as Integer
    For i = 4 To 10
        Dim d As String, row As Integer
        d = Sheet1.Range("E" & i).Value
        Sheet1.Range("E" & i).Select
        If d<>"" Then
          If d = 0 Then
              Sheet1.Range("E" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
          End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

> Change loop according to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Abhishek Tomar,
but there is a problem when compile, Error "For Without Next"

Comment: maybe you miss second last line "Next i".

Comment: Thanks alot,,, @Abhishek Tomar

Comment: If this is helpful for you please accept & vote this answer. Thanks - Glad to help.

Comment: if cell properties is text , how to overcome this error "type mis match"
by the same code >>
Sub Hide()
    For i = 4 To 10
        Dim d As String, row As Integer
        d = Sheet1.Range("E" & i).Value
        Sheet1.Range("E" & i).Select
        If d = 0 Then
            Sheet1.Range("E" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Comment: please share more information about your error because this code is working fine on my system.

Comment: if cell is empty -  no value - when make loop for this cell , error "Type mismatch " appear to me , how can i solve this error if cell contains text,
Thanks alot

Comment: Thanks you very much, -@Abhishek Tomar

Comment: :) Glad to help

Comment: Use IsNumeric function for checkin value or text..Sub IsNumericDemo()
'Use VBA to test if a cell is numeric via a subroutine
If IsNumeric(Range("A1")) = True Then
    Range("B1") = "A1 is a number"
Else
    Range("B1") = "A1 is not number"
End If
End Sub